# Sql , Select two different value from one table

Tags: sql-server

I need to select

```
Select Bid Id,date
From Bid where
Status ='Won' as successful
```

And also

```
Select Bid Id, date
From Bid where 
Status =Null as unsuccessful
```

Hello everyone i need to select two type for status in my table `bid` and display with their `id`  how can i do that please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CASE`:

```
Select Bid, Id,date, 
   WonStatus = CASE WHEN Status ='Won' THEN 'Successful' ELSE 'Unsuccessful' END
From Bid where
```

or, if you want to concat all rows, first the successful and then the unsuccessful, use `UNION ALL`:

```
Select Bid, Id,date
From Bid 
Where Status ='Won' as successful


UNION ALL

Select Bid, Id,date
From Bid 
Where Status IS NULL AS unsuccessful
```

**Edit**: "and if want to know how much is successful and how much is successful per month?"

Then this should work:

```
Select YEAR(date) AS B_Year,
       MONTH(date) AS B_Month,
       Count(*) AS Success_Count
From Bid 
Where Status = 'Won' 
GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date)
```

Comment: and if want to know how much is successful and how much is successful per month

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Bid
     , ID
     , date
     , CASE
         WHEN status IS NULL THEN 'unsuccessful'
         WHEN status = 'Won' THEN 'successful'
WHERE  status = 'Won'
    OR status IS NULL
```